# Fork and use a coffeescript npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I am using the [slack-client](https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client) library in my project, but I wanted to add a few extra functionalities, so I forked it into [my repository](https://github.com/brunosiqueira/node-slack-client/commits/release_1.4.2).

Before the PR, I wanted to test it in my own repository, so I am setting the url in my package.json:

```
"slack-client": "git+https://github.com/brunosiqueira/node-slack-client.git#release_1.4.2"
```

The problem is, and, as I don't have a lot of experience in this matter, I don't know why, the lib in node_modules/slack-client is not generating the javascript files. The lib is all coded in coffescript and, when I set the official repo in my package.json, it downloads the js files. Setting for my repo, it downloads none of the coffescripts and also do not generate the js files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743872/1765944) in a similar post, I corrected my package.json to point to the tarball

```
"slack-client": "https://github.com/brunosiqueira/node-slack-client/tarball/release_1.4.2"
```

It downloaded the coffescripts, but I still had to run **npm install** in the node_modules/slack-client directory